# Google Fusion Tables and Update JSONP Query issues

Tags: google-maps, jsonp, google-fusion-tables

I combine two examples to one, first example is for [Fusion Tables Layers Update Query from  dropdown menu](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/samples/change_query) and second example is geocodezip example for [Fusion tables hover and click polygons](http://geocodezip.com/v3_fusiontables_example_20120704.html).

Everything works fine (hover and click polygons, updateMap function etc.) except that when I want to choose values from  dropdown menu my Query not working, but when I remove WHERE clause my Query works fine. I know that I have some issues with this Query and I've spent the past 24 hours to solve this but without success, so does anyone have any suggestions?
My entire code is shown below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Fusion Tables Layer Example: Update Query from  dropdown menu and Mouseover Map Styles</title>

<style type="text/css">
<!--
.style1 {
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #333333;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.style2 {
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #333333;
}
-->

</style>
  </head>
  <body>

<link href="/apis/fusiontables/docs/samples/style/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
      var tableId = '1m13iFNXZhKPYKWVTKSVoa8mPxlCrQpNzkpsM4ys';
      var tableId2 = '18VSkr75quvARXc7s2xMZ9T4PJH84Ffbua-x4klw';
      var colors = ['#FF0000', '#00FF00', '#0000FF', '#FFFF00'];
      var map;
      var geometry = 'geometry';

      function initialize() {
        var myOptions = {
          zoom: 6,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-40.979898,173.305662),
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
              myOptions);


        var layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
          query: {
            select: geometry,
            from: tableId
          },
            styles: [{
            polygonOptions: {
            strokeColor: "#333333",
            strokeOpacity: 0.8,
            strokeWeight: 0.7,
            fillColor: "#006600",
            fillOpacity: 0.3
                }
            }],
          map: map
        });

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('regional_council'),
        'change', function() {
        updateMap(layer, layer2, tableId, tableId2, geometry);
        });

        // Initialize JSONP request
        var layer2 = document.createElement('script');
        var url = ['https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?'];
        url.push('sql=');
        var query = 'SELECT name, geometry FROM ' + tableId2 + 'WHERE regional_council = "+ regional_council +"';
        var encodedQuery = encodeURIComponent(query);
        url.push(encodedQuery);
        url.push('&callback=drawMap');
        url.push('&key=AIzaSyAm9yWCV7JPCTHCJut8whOjARd7pwROFDQ');
        layer2.src = url.join('');
        var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
        body.appendChild(layer2);
      }

      function createPolygon(country,id)
      {
            google.maps.event.addListener(country, 'mouseover', function() {
              this.setOptions({fillOpacity: 1});
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(country, 'mouseout', function() {
              this.setOptions({fillOpacity: 0.3});
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(country, 'click', function() {
              document.getElementById('content-window').innerHTML = id;
            });
      }

      function drawMap(data) {
        var rows = data['rows'];
        for (var i in rows) {
          if (rows[i][0] != 'Antarctica') {
            var id = rows[i][0];
            var newCoordinates = [];
            var geometries = rows[i][1]['geometries'];
            if (geometries) {
              for (var j in geometries) {
                newCoordinates.push(constructNewCoordinates(geometries[j]));
              }
            } else {
              newCoordinates = constructNewCoordinates(rows[i][1]['geometry']);
            }
            var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
            var country = new google.maps.Polygon({
              paths: newCoordinates,
              strokeColor: colors[randomnumber],
              strokeOpacity: 0,
              strokeWeight: 1,
              fillColor: colors[randomnumber],
              fillOpacity: 0.3
            });
            createPolygon(country,id);

            country.setMap(map);
          }
        }
      }

      function constructNewCoordinates(polygon) {
        var newCoordinates = [];
        var coordinates = polygon['coordinates'][0];
        for (var i in coordinates) {
          newCoordinates.push(
              new google.maps.LatLng(coordinates[i][1], coordinates[i][0]));
        }
        return newCoordinates;
      }


        function updateMap(layer, layer2, tableId, tableId2, geometry) {
        var regional_council = document.getElementById('regional_council').value;
        if (regional_council) {
        layer.setMap(null);
        layer2.setMap(map);
        } else {
        layer.setMap(map);
        layer2.setMap(null);
        }
      }

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>

<div id="map-canvas" style="position:absolute; left:365px; top:30px; width:800px; height:825px; border-style:solid; border-width:1px; border-color:#333333;"></div>
<div id="panel_1" style="position:absolute; left:10px; top:30px; width:200px; height:50px;" class="style1">Select Regional Council:</span><br>
<span class="style2">*Select Regional Council from the list</span></div>
<div id="panel_2" style="position:absolute; left:210px; top:30px; width:150px; height:50px;">
    <select id="regional_council">
      <option value="">--Select--</option>
      <option value="Auckland">Auckland</option>
      <option value="Bay of Plenty">Bay of Plenty</option>
      <option value="Canterbury">Canterbury</option>
      <option value="Gisborne">Gisborne</option>
      <option value="Hawkes Bay">Hawke's Bay</option>
      <option value="Manawatu-Wanganui">Manawatu-Wanganui</option>
      <option value="Marlborough">Marlborough</option>
      <option value="Nelson">Nelson</option>
      <option value="Northland">Northland</option>
      <option value="Otago">Otago</option>
      <option value="Southland">Southland</option>
      <option value="Taranaki">Taranaki</option>
      <option value="Waikato">Waikato</option>
      <option value="Wellington">Wellington</option>
      <option value="West Coast">West Coast</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div id="panel_3" style="position:absolute; left:10px; top:90px; width:200px; height:50px;"><span class="style1">Select Area Unit:</span><br>
<span class="style2">*Select Area Unit by clicking on the Polygon</span></div>
<div id="content-window" style="position:absolute; left:210px; top:90px; width:150px; height:50px; background-color: #CCCCCC; layer-background-color: #CCCCCC; border: 1px none #000000;"></div>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Look at the javascript error: `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLScriptElement> has no method 'setMap'` on line 140.

Comment: If I understand problem my `layer2` doesn't contain objects of type `google.maps.FusionTablesLayer` but it contains HTMLScriptElement element objects because of this `var layer2 = document.createElement('script');` ? So can I get with this approach (`var layer2 = document.createElement('script');`) result that I want, or I need to change my approach? Some example will be great.

Comment: That is certainly the first order problem (layer2 is an "HTMLScriptElement", not a Google Maps Javascript API v3 object). If you want to hide/show the polygons displayed by that query, you need to keep references to them (a global array would be simplest), then call the setMap method on those.  I don't understand the user interface you are looking to create.  Do you need to run the query again?  Or just use the results of the original query?

Comment: I need to run Query `SELECT name, geometry FROM ' + tableId2 + 'WHERE regional_council = "+ regional_council +"';` every time a user select new Regional Concil from dropdown menu, then map need to show all Area Unit that belong to selected Regional Concil (and old map with some other Area Unit that belong to previously selected Regional Concil need to be update).

Comment: I try to add this part of code to create Google Maps Javascript API v3 object for layer 2 `var list = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer;
      function getList(layer2){
      list.push(layer2);
      }` and also change this part of code `if (regional_council) {
        layer.setMap(null);
        list.setMap(map);
        } else {
        layer.setMap(map);
        list.setMap(null);` but without success